# Define issue in C++ for derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation

I have 2 Classes deriving from the same API, 
and  want to be able to use the same API for both of them the only difference between the two is a define I need to put outside the API which will determine a something in the results returned by the joint function.

I'm having an issue with my design, I inherit this API and I can't change it.

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Version100.h"
#include "Version200.h"

int main()
{
    Version100* ver100 = new Version100();
    int res  = ver100->PlusOne(2);
    Version200* ver200 = new Version200();
    res  = ver200->PlusOne(2);
}
```

**VersionAPI.h** - this is the API I inherit I can't change this implementation

```
#pragma once
class VersionAPI
{
public:
    VersionAPI(void);
    ~VersionAPI(void);
    int PlusOne(int number);

};
```

**VersionAPI.cpp** - the problem I have is that I need to use different VERSION define for every class

```
#include "VersionAPI.h"


VersionAPI::VersionAPI(void)
{
}


VersionAPI::~VersionAPI(void)
{
}


int VersionAPI::PlusOne(int number)
{
    return number + VERSION;
}
```

**Version100.h**

```
#pragma once
#define VERSION 100 

#include "VersionAPI.h"


class Version100 :
    public VersionAPI
{
public:
    Version100(void);
    ~Version100(void);
};
```

**Version100.cpp**

```
#include "Version100.h"


Version100::Version100(void)
{
}


Version100::~Version100(void)
{
}
```

**Version200.h**

```
#pragma once

#define VERSION 200
#include "versionapi.h"
class Version200 :
    public VersionAPI
{
public:
    Version200(void);
    ~Version200(void);
};
```

**Version200.cpp**

```
#include "Version200.h"


Version200::Version200(void)
{
}


Version200::~Version200(void)
{
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ersionapi.cpp(16): error C2065: 'VERSION' : undeclared identifier

I know this if because VERSION is defined outside the class.

Comment: Make it a static member of each class, instead of a `define`.

Comment: but the API i inherit uses define. @juanchopanza

Comment: @Gilad Badly designed API, good luck :-/ ...

Comment: Oh dear! Wow, I guess it is "tough luck" then. Or use a less crappy API.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you give the full answer how it should look like? i need to change the define it static member in the API as well?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. How can the translation unit `VersionAPI.cpp` be compiled at the moment?

Comment: @KerrekSB i also can't see a way to do it without breaking the API or copying the code into two different projects...?

Comment: @Gilad it would be like NirMH's answer, but with static members.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your code already has undefined behaviour, because it violates the one-definition rule.

Comment: VersionAPI.cpp has a dependency on the name/definition VERSION.
It only includes VersionAPI.h which doesn't define VERSION.
This won't compile as shown.

Comment: @Gilad I added a sketch of a solution. It requires that you remove the define.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks very much i need to go and break some heads for that. will see if i can make this work. thanks a lot.

Comment: @juanchopanza i will leave this question open for another day before i accept your answer. maybe someone else will have another idea

Comment: That's a good approach. BTW, you need the destructor to be `virtual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the public part of the API intact, and add a `private` virtual function that returns the version. The version itself can be a `static` member, which is different for each derived type, or just a value returned from the `version()` virtual function:

```
class VersionAPI
{
public:
    VersionAPI();
    virtual ~VersionAPI();        // Don't forget the virtual derstuctor!!!
    int PlusOne(int number) const // mark "final" in C++11 
    { 
      return version() + number;
    }

private:
    virtual int version() const { return 123; }
};
```

Then implement `version() const` in the derived types, returning the relevant version number.

```
class Version200 : public VersionAPI
{
public:
  Version200();
  ~Version200();
private:
  virtual int version() const { return 200; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the `VERSION` as a member of each derived class and in the `VersionApi` make the `PlusOne` method `virtual`.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the virtual ?

Comment: well, as you required specific `child` behavior, i don't see how this can be done... that what `Virtual` is for. and usually API or interface should be `virtual`